# How can i add loading spinner before fetching data in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

What is the correct way to add a spinner while fetching data from API in react js? I tried to display the spinner until the `data.length > 0` it works fine when the data is more than zero. But when it is actually zero, the loading spinner doesn't stop. Is there any good solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't provide enough info or code to tell exactly what to do but i will give you a simple example

just create a state for the loading set it true and when the fetch is done set it false

I hope this example is clear

```
import { useEffect,useState } from 'react'

export default function Page() {
    const [data, setData] = useState(null)
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true)

    useEffect(() => {
        fetch('/api/test',{method: 'GET'})
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(data => {
            console.log(data)
            setData(data)
        }
        )
        .catch(err => {
            console.log(err)
        }
        )
        .finally(() => {
            setLoading(false)
        })
    }, [])
    if(loading) return <div>Loading...</div> // or your loading spinner
    return (
    <div>{JSON.stringify(data)}</div>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a loader as a standalone hook and utilize it whenever necessary for displaying within components or pages.

Context:

```
export const SContext = createContext<ISpinner | undefined>(undefined);
export const SProvider: React.FC<ISpinner> = ({ children }) => {
  const [spinnerVisible, setSpinnerVisible] = useState(false);

  const showSpinner = () => {
    setSpinnerVisible(true);
  };

  const hideSpinner = () => {
    setSpinnerVisible(false);
  };

  return (
    <SpinnerContext.Provider value={{ showSpinner, hideSpinner }}>
      {children}
      {spinnerVisible && <Spinner></Spinner>}
    </SpinnerContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

Hook

```
export const useSpinner = () => {
  const context = useContext(SContext);
  if (context === undefined) {
    throw new Error('Spinner Error');
  }
  return context;
};
```

Inside Component needs to access:

```
const { showSpinner, hideSpinner } = useSpinner();
```